# Derivation of Grassmann valued functional

Tags: functional-analysis, grassmannian

I'm trying to evaluate
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta(x)}e^{-\int dz \theta^*(z)\eta(z)}$$
Where $\theta^*(x)$ and $\eta(x)$ are Grassmann valued functions. The context of the functional is in term of functions that can be expressed in a basis of orthonormal functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ such that 
$$\eta(x)=\sum_n\eta_n f_n(x)$$ 
where $\eta_n$ is Grassmann number, which means that for any two Grassmann numbers, $a$, $b$ then $ab=-ba$ and so $a^2=0$, etc.

The definition of the derivative is such that
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta(x)}\eta(y)=\delta(x-y)$$
With that it is easy to show that 
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta(x)}e^{-\int dz \theta^*(z)\eta(z)}=\theta^*(x)$$
However, this should be also equal to 
$$\theta^*(x)e^{-\int dz \theta^*(z)\eta(z)}$$
Which should be possible to show by noticing the property that $a^2=0$ (I think), so by a Taylor expansion
$$\theta^*(x)=^?\theta^*(x)-\int \theta^*(x) \theta^*(z)\eta(z)dz=\theta^*(x)e^{-\int dz \theta^*(z)\eta(z)}$$
But I'm failing to see how the integral is zero. I tried working out whether $\theta^*(x)\theta^*(z)$ is zero alone by expanding the functions in the basis:
$$\theta^*(x)\theta^*(z)=\sum_n \theta^2_nf^*_n(x)f^*_n(y)+\sum_{n<m}\theta_n \theta_m (f^*_n(x)f^*_m(y)-f^*_m(x)f^*_n(y))$$
The only properties of the $f$ I know are the orthogonality:
$$\int dx f^*_m(x)f_n(x)=\delta_{mn}$$
and the completeness condition
$$\sum_n f^*_n(x)f_n(y)=\delta(x-y)$$
But I don't think I can use those.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but better late than never. I think the statement 
\begin{equation}\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)}e^{-\int \mathrm{d}z \theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)}=\theta^{*} (x)\end{equation} is wrong. The exponential doesn't disappear when you differentiate, so it should read 
\begin{equation}\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)}e^{-\int \mathrm{d}z \theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)}=e^{-\int \mathrm{d}z \,\theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)}\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)} \int \mathrm{d}z\, \eta(z) \theta^{*}(z)\right)\end{equation}
Here I've switched $\eta(z)$ and $\theta^{*}(z)$ to get rid of the minus sign. (You could also note that Grassmann derivatives also anticommute, so $\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)}\theta^{*}(z)=-\theta^{*}\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)}$ to get rid of the negative sign). 
The next step is simply evaluating the functional derivative, which according to the property 
\begin{equation}\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)} \eta(z)=\delta(x-z)\end{equation}
you've listed just gives a final result of
\begin{equation}\frac{\delta}{\delta \eta (x)}e^{-\int \mathrm{d}z \theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)}=e^{-\int \mathrm{d}z \theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)}\theta^{*}(x)\end{equation}
Another potential source of confusion could be how to deal with a Taylor expansion of 
\begin{equation}e^{-\int \mathrm{d}z\, \eta(z)\theta^{*}(z)\eta (z)}\end{equation}
It goes just like you think it would, but remember when you raise an integral to a power, you have to integrate over a separate region for each power. For example 
\begin{equation}\left(\int \mathrm{d}z\,\theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)\right)^{2}=\int \mathrm{d}z \int \mathrm{d}x\ (\theta^{*}(z)\eta(z)\theta^{*}(x)\eta(x))\end{equation}
Here, $\eta(z)$ and $\eta(x)$ are different Grassmann variables, so that $\eta(z)\eta(x)\neq 0$ and the integral doesn't vanish. 
Hope this helps, even this late.

Comment: On the second equation's RHS, you have written the exponential term at first and then the functional derivative term. How do we know that the exponential term will be at first and then the functional derivative term? What is the corresponding chain rule?